# Is incrementing a map iterator in else part of ternary operator corect?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Is code in Method 1 incorrect (using ternary operator). Does ++it has undefined evaluation order here. Or both methods are same:

**Method 1:**

```
struct X
{
    int id;
    int j;
};

void delete_data_from_map(map<int,X>& my_map, int const id)
{
    for(auto it {my_map.begin()}; it != my_map.end();)
    {
        it = (it->second.id == id) ? my_map.erase(it) : ++it;
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
void delete_data_from_map(map<int,X>& my_map, int const id)
{
    for(auto it {my_map.begin()}; it != my_map.end();)
    {
        if(it->second.id == id)
             it = my_map.erase(it);
        else ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile. An `int` doesn't have any member named `id`.

Comment: sorry , let  me change

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes. But I thought an iterator is different from fundamental types. Thats why asked in this way.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Also I recommend to rewrite the ternary as `if-else` and see if you still have the same doubts

Comment: Actually, I'm not so sure anymore that just `it = ++it;` is equivalent. The common type of the two branches may play a part here too.

Comment: Either way, what are you compiling this as? C++17? It's important to specify the dialect if you ask about the construct being correct or not.

Comment: In C++20, `std::erase_if` saves the day.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica As C++17. If language does not proclaims the behaviour in method 1 as undefined, there must be no reason to not use that.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have not moved to c++20 yet :).

Comment: There can be a reason that has nothing to do with the language. If a quirk of the standard library implementation you use causes a bug, you may want to not use too clever an expression. Such things happen unfortunately.

Comment: @virus00x - One final question. Are you using MSVC by any chance?

Comment: @virus00x There is a third approach that will work for any C++ Standard. it->second.id == id ? it = my_map.erase(it) : ++it;

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica No mate. its GCC 10.2

Comment: I'm pretty sure `it = ++it;` is UB. But maybe not from c++17.

Comment: Btw, writing a multiline `if() ... else` without braces invites `goto fail;` style bugs. Better add braces the moment you add a second line, even without an `else`.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Not in a world with linters and formatters.

Comment: @Acorn No linter would have barked at the `goto fail;` in Apples code. A code formatter may signal back to the programmer how the code is actually going to be interpreted, but it still requires human vigilance to actually catch the bug. Since I always add braces when a statement spans more than a single line, I'm much safer from my own stupidity than if I relied on tools to format my code.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Then you need better tools. Linters that warn when the indentation is wrong or misleading do exist (for many years, actually) and are quite easy to write (specially if your code base enforces several rules to make it even easier). No need to rely on inspection at all.

Answer (score 4):

There are three issues at play. One is the semantics of the ternary operator: only one of the possibilities of the conditional operator is evaluated. From [expr.cond]:

> Only one of the second and third expressions is evaluated.

Further, you can rely that the chosen one will not start until the condition has fully ended:

> Every value computation and side effect associated with the first expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the second or third expression.

The second issue is the semantics of `it = ++it;`: a type may behave logically in a different way when assigned after an increment. Usually, we don't expect types to change the observable behavior, but we can't tell. It is best to write what you want: just the increment `++it;`.

Finally, there is the topic of `it = ++it;` being UB pre-C++17 and whether you want to tie your code to that version.

---

Conclusion: it is best to write a plain `if` for this, precisely because the precise semantics and fear of UB is not worth it.

Comment: `it = ++it;` is fine starting with C++17, was UB before. See (20) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks, I wasn't aware of that change.

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide enough context, therefore, I am guessing you want to search multiple items on some other attribute (not the key) and remove them.

If that assumption is correct that either approach is fine since you are incrementing the iterator to next element if the current one does not match your search condition.

Although, I would still recommend the `if-else` one because that is more clearer to the reader and also avoids any lingering sequence point issues the ternary version may have.

Comment: I just want to know if language thinks it as undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Since `it` is of type `map<int,X>::iterator`, the expression

```
it = (it->second.id == id) ? my_map.erase(it) : ++it;
```

is well-defined **in this case**, because `++it` is actually a function call; the update that happens inside the function is sequenced before the assignment expression.